# Is it possible to use the ElementType Modal UI for a custom Field Type Plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

So I'm writing a plugin to try and create a relationship between two entry sections that is a two way street (Many to Many).

I would love to co-opt the UI and functionality of the ElementType modal for a predefined section ID and then do my own saving logic.

In other words, I would just like to use the front end form functionality and handle the backend logic myself. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep, you can do that with `Craft.createElementSelectorModal()`:

```
var myModal = Craft.createElementSelectorModal('Entry', {
    resizable:          true,
    storageKey:         'someUniqueID',
    sources:            ['section:1', 'seciton:2'],
    criteria:           { status: null },
    multiSelect:        true,
    disabledElementIds: [1, 2, 3],
    disableOnSelect:    true,
    onCancel:           function(){},
    onSelect:           function(entries){}
});
```

The first argument specifies what *type* of element you want to be selecting (Entry, Asset, etc.), and the second argument defines the settings.

All of those settings are optional except for `onSelect`. Here’s what they do:

- **`resizable`** *(bool)* – Whether the modal should be user-resizable. (Defaults to `true`)
- **`storageKey`** *(string)* – The storage key prefix that the modal will use to save its state in the browser’s localStorage, including things like which source was selected. (Defaults to `null`)
- **`sources`** *(array)* – Which sources should be shown in the modal’s sidebar. If omitted, all sources will be shown. (Defaults to `null`)
- **`criteria`** *(object)* – The params that will be used to determine which elements will be shown. See the [craft.entries documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries) for available params when selecting entries. (Defaults to `null`)
- **`multiSelect`** *(bool)* – Whether multiple elements should be able to be selected at once. (Defaults to `false`)
- **`disabledElementIds`** *(array)* – A list of element IDs that should be disabled (unselectable). Pass any elements that are already selected in here, so they can’t be double-selected. (Defaults to an empty array)
- **`disableOnSelect`** *(bool)* – Whether the modal should automatically disable elements when they are selected. (Defaults to `false`)
- **`onCancel`** *(function)* – A function that should get called when the modal is cancelled without selecting anything.
- **`onSelect`** *(function)* – A function that should get called when elements have been selected.

The `onSelect` function will get passed an array that contains info about each of the selected elements. Each item in the array will have the following properties:

- **`id`** – The element’s ID
- **`label`** – The element’s label (the Title if it’s an entry)
- **`status`** – The element’s status
- **`url`** – The element’s front-end URL, if it has one
- **`hasThumb`** – Whether the element has a thumbnail
- **`$element`** – A jQuery object for the element, which you can append to your field input

Once you’ve created your modal, it will automatically be shown. It will also be automatically closed when it is cancelled out of, or elements are selected.

You can re-open it later by calling `myModal.show()`.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks Brandon! I'll keep you updated on how this goes.

Comment: This is _insanely_ helpful. Thanks for the great documentation.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this except the modal shows all element types?

Comment: @BenjaminKohl Sorry, no.

Comment: Is it possible to use this modal with custom data rather than an element type? I want to use it to interface a REST-API.

Comment: @Luke no, but you could reuse the styles and copy the JS as a starting point in building your own modal.