# How would I change "disabledElementIds" when using createElementSelectorModal()?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm using the createElementsSelectorModal to access certain element types as described by Brandon [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/895/is-it-possible-to-use-the-elementtype-modal-ui-for-a-custom-field-type-plugin)

With this implementation, how would I clear out "disabledElementIds"? So that if an Entry is added and then removed I can tell the Modal it should be selectable again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements can be manually enabled/disabled from the modal after it has been initialized using the following methods:

```
myModal.elementIndex.enableElementsById(elementIds);
```

and

```
myModal.elementIndex.disableElementsById(elementIds);
```

Both functions accept a number (single element ID) or an array of numbers (multiple element IDs).

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I appreciate the quick response. I'm not 100% sure I'm using this correctly. If I didn't want the modal to pop up automatically and I wanted to reuse the modal if my Field Type plugin is added to the page multiple times, how would I go about this?

Comment: Just don’t create the modal in your JS until it’s actually needed.

Comment: Fair enough, that is kind of what I'm doing. I wrapped a function around creating the modal and call it on a click event, passing in the parameters I need. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this probably wasn't the best way to go about it, but I solved this by manually defining what is un-selectable:

```
var unSelectable = [1,2,3]
```

And then I keep track of the array as things happen in the DOM and pop items in and out. Then, I pass them to the function I use to call Craft.createElementSelectorModal() setting disabledElementIds manually:

```
disabledElementIds: unSelectable,
```