# Using elementSelect for third-party elements

Tags: fieldtypes, plugin-craftcommerce

I'm writing plugin to extend Craft Commerce and I want to present a good way to select products in CP.

I know I could use dropdown select for this, but using Craft's elementSelect would make the UI much nicer. Is there a way to use elementSelect dialog / fieldtype not just for entries or assets, but for custom data set (in my case, Commerce Products)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to a custom field to select products, one already exists:

[image: screenshot of product field type]

If you are building a general attribute field for a plugin, taking a look at the B `BaseElementFieldType.php` within the craft/app filder (that the product field above extends) will give you clues on how to recreate the UI to select products (or any other element).

The key file being `craft/app/templates/_includes/forms/elementSelect.html` which will show you how to instantiate the `Craft.BaseElementSelectInput` js class.

Hope that points you in the right direction. I am not sure if there is a full guide out there on how to use`Craft.BaseElementSelectInput` js, but hopefully the above will get you most of the way there by looking at the code.

Comment: Thanks Luke - do you perhaps know any way to use Commerce Product fieldtype directly in my plugin? That would be the best way around probably.

Comment: Take a looks at http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/895/is-it-possible-to-use-the-elementtype-modal-ui-for-a-custom-field-type-plugin

Comment: If you want to use the fieldtype you would need to make your record an element type in craft to allow custom fields to be added to it.